# Convert text from txt file into json using jq tool

Tags: json, bash, jq, data-conversion, gsutil

I have a txt file with values obtained by calling the following command recursively: `gsutil ls -r gs://bucket-test/** | while IFS= read -r key; do gsutil stat $key; done`, it looks like this:

```
gs://bucket-test/4e123978-8eed-43ae-f521-8fba54c704ea.zip:
    Creation time:          Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT
    Update time:            Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Length:         0
    Content-Type:           application/zip
    Hash (crc32c):          AAAAAA==
    Hash (md5):             1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==
    ETag:                   CM30q9XCivwCEAE=
    Generation:             1671619167320653
    Metageneration:         1
gs://bucket-test/GKiSQMZ5rAqrSWwur/uploads/GENERAL/SNrQD97nzQN9eDLeA/AAZYefiL5CT8pxe4L:
    Creation time:          Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT
    Update time:            Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Disposition:    inline; filename=James_INGREDIENTS_A3.pdf
    Content-Length:         4381797
    Content-Type:           application/pdf
    Hash (crc32c):          GOzitA==
    Hash (md5):             eUSLC/z70gjDB2WQKIPOuQ==
    ETag:                   CLGPvu+BoP4CEAE=
    Generation:             1681153781106609
    Metageneration:         1
gs://bucket-test/prova.pdf:
    Creation time:          Mon, 08 May 2023 15:37:26 GMT
    Update time:            Mon, 08 May 2023 15:40:12 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Disposition:    inline; filename=James_KEY_VISUAL_A3.pdf
    Content-Language:       ace
    Content-Length:         15407
    Content-Type:           application/pdf
    Metadata:               
        meta-1:             prova 1
        meta-2:             prova 2
    Hash (crc32c):          ZIrHPA==
    Hash (md5):             oZbD+S8y35spkNozW3hUDA==
    ETag:                   CNDj09OG5v4CEAM=
    Generation:             1683560246604240
    Metageneration:         3
```

I need to convert the output to json format, splitting by leading spaces and assigning the value present on the first row of each group to the "Key" field, then there may be subfields for example under the "Metadata" value:

```
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/4e123978-8eed-43ae-f521-8fba54c704ea.zip",
  "Creation time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
  "Update time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Length": "0",
  "Content-Type": "application/zip",
  "Hash (crc32c)": "AAAAAA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
  "ETag": "CM30q9XCivwCEAE=",
  "Generation": "1671619167320653",
  "Metageneration": "1"
},
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/GKiSQMZ5rAqrSWwur/uploads/GENERAL/SNrQD97nzQN9eDLeA/AAZYefiL5CT8pxe4L",
  "Creation time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
  "Update time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_INGREDIENTS_A3.pdf",
  "Content-Length": "4381797",
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Hash (crc32c)": "GOzitA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "eUSLC/z70gjDB2WQKIPOuQ==",
  "ETag": "CLGPvu+BoP4CEAE=",
  "Generation": "1681153781106609",
  "Metageneration": "1"
},
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/prova.pdf",
  "Creation time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:37:26 GMT",
  "Update time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:40:12 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_KEY_VISUAL_A3.pdf",
  "Content-Language": "ace",
  "Content-Length": "15407",
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Metadata": {
    "meta-1": "prova 1",
    "meta-2": "prova 2"
  },
  "Hash (crc32c)": "ZIrHPA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "oZbD+S8y35spkNozW3hUDA==",
  "ETag": "CNDj09OG5v4CEAM=",
  "Generation": "1683560246604240",
  "Metageneration": "3"
}
```

I tried with this command for an only group but without success:
`gsutil stat gs://bucket-test/prova.pdf | printf %s "$(cat)" | jq -R -s 'split("\n") | map({key: split(": ")[0], value: split(": ")[1]})'`

The json is converted into an array:

```
[
  {
    "key": "gs://spin8-test/prova.pdf:",
    "value": null
  },
  {
    "key": "    Creation time",
    "value": "         Mon, 08 May 2023 15:37:26 GMT"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Update time",
    "value": "           Mon, 08 May 2023 15:40:12 GMT"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Storage class",
    "value": "         STANDARD"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Content-Disposition",
    "value": "   inline; filename=James_KEY_VISUAL_A3.pdf"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Content-Language",
    "value": "      ace"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Content-Length",
    "value": "        15407"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Content-Type",
    "value": "          application/pdf"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Metadata",
    "value": "              "
  },
  {
    "key": "        meta-1",
    "value": "            prova 1"
  },
  {
    "key": "        meta-2",
    "value": "            prova 2"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Hash (crc32c)",
    "value": "         ZIrHPA=="
  },
  {
    "key": "    Hash (md5)",
    "value": "            oZbD+S8y35spkNozW3hUDA=="
  },
  {
    "key": "    ETag",
    "value": "                  CNDj09OG5v4CEAM="
  },
  {
    "key": "    Generation",
    "value": "            1683560246604240"
  },
  {
    "key": "    Metageneration",
    "value": "        3"
  }
]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jq, you can read in raw text using the `-R` flag, and iterate through the lines using `reduce`. Start out with an empty array `[]`, then, based on the indentation, add a new item, append to the `last` one, or append to `last` one's `.Metadata` field. Checking the indentation and parsing the line's content is done using regular expressions with `match` and `capture`, respectively:

```bash
jq -Rn '
  reduce (inputs | {
    ind: match("^\\s*").length,
    cap: capture("\\s*(?<key>.*):(\\s+(?<value>.*))?$")
  }) as {$ind, $cap} ([];
    if $ind == 0 then . + [$cap | {key}]
    elif $ind == 4 then last += ([$cap | select(.key == "Metadata").value = {}] | from_entries)
    elif $ind == 8 then last.Metadata += ([$cap] | from_entries)
    else . end
  )
'
```

This creates a valid JSON array (because without the brackets but with commas in between the items, it wouldn't be valid JSON):

```json
[
  {
    "key": "gs://bucket-test/4e123978-8eed-43ae-f521-8fba54c704ea.zip",
    "Creation time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
    "Update time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
    "Storage class": "STANDARD",
    "Content-Length": "0",
    "Content-Type": "application/zip",
    "Hash (crc32c)": "AAAAAA==",
    "Hash (md5)": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
    "ETag": "CM30q9XCivwCEAE=",
    "Generation": "1671619167320653",
    "Metageneration": "1"
  },
  {
    "key": "gs://bucket-test/GKiSQMZ5rAqrSWwur/uploads/GENERAL/SNrQD97nzQN9eDLeA/AAZYefiL5CT8pxe4L",
    "Creation time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
    "Update time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
    "Storage class": "STANDARD",
    "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_INGREDIENTS_A3.pdf",
    "Content-Length": "4381797",
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    "Hash (crc32c)": "GOzitA==",
    "Hash (md5)": "eUSLC/z70gjDB2WQKIPOuQ==",
    "ETag": "CLGPvu+BoP4CEAE=",
    "Generation": "1681153781106609",
    "Metageneration": "1"
  },
  {
    "key": "gs://bucket-test/prova.pdf",
    "Creation time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:37:26 GMT",
    "Update time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:40:12 GMT",
    "Storage class": "STANDARD",
    "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_KEY_VISUAL_A3.pdf",
    "Content-Language": "ace",
    "Content-Length": "15407",
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    "Metadata": {
      "meta-1": "prova 1",
      "meta-2": "prova 2"
    },
    "Hash (crc32c)": "ZIrHPA==",
    "Hash (md5)": "oZbD+S8y35spkNozW3hUDA==",
    "ETag": "CNDj09OG5v4CEAM=",
    "Generation": "1683560246604240",
    "Metageneration": "3"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/drb3Z7WE08a)

Comment: Thanks, it misses only a thing: the command doesn't parse the subfields under "Metadata" field.

Now it prints

"Metadata": "",
"meta-1": "prova 1",
"meta-2": "prova 2",

Here I need it becomes:
```

"Metadata": {
  "meta-1": "prova 1",
  "meta-2": "prova 2"
}

Comment: @Marco Oh, I didn't see that. Fixing it ... Is the "Metadata" keyword always fixed or should it apply to any (second) indentation?

Comment: The "Metadata" keyword is present only if set, in that case it contains one or more subelements with pair key-value

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea how you'd use `jq` to parse regular text to turn it into JSON or if that's even something `jq` is designed to do but here's a **start** using `awk` to just handle the input/output you show:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[^[:space:]]/ { if (NR>1) prtRec() }
{ rec = rec $0 RS }
END { prtRec(); print "" }

function prtRec(        lines,numLines,lineNr,line,tag,val,depth) {
    printf "%s", recSep
    recSep = "," ORS

    print "{"

    numLines = split(rec,lines,RS) - 1
    for ( lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++ ) {
        line = lines[lineNr]
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",line)
        tag = val = line
        if ( lineNr == 1 ) {
            tag = "Key"
            sub(/:$/,"",val)
        }
        else {
            sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",tag)
            sub(/[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",val)
        }
        printf "  \"%s\": \"%s\"%s\n", tag, val, (lineNr<numLines ? "," : "")
    }

    printf "}"

    rec = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/4e123978-8eed-43ae-f521-8fba54c704ea.zip",
  "Creation time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
  "Update time": "Wed, 21 Dec 2022 10:39:27 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Length": "0",
  "Content-Type": "application/zip",
  "Hash (crc32c)": "AAAAAA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg==",
  "ETag": "CM30q9XCivwCEAE=",
  "Generation": "1671619167320653",
  "Metageneration": "1"
},
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/GKiSQMZ5rAqrSWwur/uploads/GENERAL/SNrQD97nzQN9eDLeA/AAZYefiL5CT8pxe4L",
  "Creation time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
  "Update time": "Mon, 10 Apr 2023 19:09:41 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_INGREDIENTS_A3.pdf",
  "Content-Length": "4381797",
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Hash (crc32c)": "GOzitA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "eUSLC/z70gjDB2WQKIPOuQ==",
  "ETag": "CLGPvu+BoP4CEAE=",
  "Generation": "1681153781106609",
  "Metageneration": "1"
},
{
  "Key": "gs://bucket-test/prova.pdf",
  "Creation time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:37:26 GMT",
  "Update time": "Mon, 08 May 2023 15:40:12 GMT",
  "Storage class": "STANDARD",
  "Content-Disposition": "inline; filename=James_KEY_VISUAL_A3.pdf",
  "Content-Language": "ace",
  "Content-Length": "15407",
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Metadata": "",
  "meta-1": "prova 1",
  "meta-2": "prova 2",
  "Hash (crc32c)": "ZIrHPA==",
  "Hash (md5)": "oZbD+S8y35spkNozW3hUDA==",
  "ETag": "CNDj09OG5v4CEAM=",
  "Generation": "1683560246604240",
  "Metageneration": "3"
}
```

You'd just have to modify it to spot the missing `val` on the `Metadata` line and use the increase/decrease of the indent on the subsequent lines to add the necessary additional `{` and `}`.

Comment: I'm using jq because I'm developing backup and restore scripts of a Google bucket. Before I make a dump (tar.gz) of objects from a bucket and all their metadata saved on a txt file. From here, I need to restore the objects from a dump, for each object I have to set its metadata searching its corresponding from the txt file, so I'm thinking to use jq tool with its searching functions, at example with following command: METADATA=$(jq 'select(.Key == "'$KEY'").Metadata' < metadata.json).

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how that's related to your question of converting some text to JSON but I hope someone can help you with that. Good luck.